# How to access just the field name in mongo document in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I am uploading big data files in mongo and want to display them as graphs. But I have too many fields to manually type out the fields when graphing. Any help with graphing mongo collection documents in this manner is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the term "graphing"?

Comment: For example, displaying all the fields that have a number as bar graph

Comment: Now I understand. Can you show some code on how you currently try to render the graph and which of the fields exactly should be left out?

Comment: I'm a beginner with meteor/html so I don't even know how to begin the process of data visualization. Unfortunately, I've only been trying to display data without any graphics so far. 
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5abd3e21eb76ed64abee8c7a"),
 "INT_01" : 51,
 "INT_02" : 56,
 "INT_03" : 47,
 "INT_04" : 63,
}
I have multiple files like this and would like to display a histogram per field, e.g. accumulating all the data from the INT_01 field and presenting that data.

Comment: There are good libraries out there that already do that for you by only requiring a very few lines. (Cough, Plotly, cough). You can do some research one them and experiment around. If you stuck you can **edit** this question and add some code examples on where you get stuck.

Comment: I'm looking for more reactive graphs. My idea is once a field is clicked, a plot of that data would show and another dropdown option can appear to and another query narrowing the search. I'm thinking of using D3 plots. Thanks for your help!